# Windows 10 context menu modification

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1903, windows-terminal

I am not able to find it on the web, so maybe here, it will be a good place to ask.

Is there a possibility to change the right-click menu on the "Windows icon"? I would like to replace default Windows PowerShell and Windows PowerShell (Administrator) with windows terminal. Does anyone made a similar modification?

[image]

Comment: I will delete my answer so you can start again. Default Windows only permits Powershell or Command

Comment: Any registry magic? I searched for related antry but no luck, since I am not very experienced with it.

Comment: I have not seen any.

Comment: There is a way to add shortcut in Win+X menu instead of replacing.

Comment: @Biswapriyo teach me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check contents of C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\
Here is Group1, Group2, Group3 with default right-click menu on "Start" shortcuts.

Just remove unnecessary shortcuts and put your favorite shortcuts here (will change after explorer.exe restart or PC reboot)

Comment: I am not sure, but is seems that new shortcuts are not being added. But when shorcut is removed it does affect rmb menu

Comment: Ouch, it's allow to add "trusted" shortcuts only...

But check this link with some details about this issue and link to utility (hashlnk) wich allow to process .lnk files to put it to this menu: https://withinrafael.com/2014/04/05/the-winx-menu-and-its-hashing-algorithm/
It rather old but seems still working...


If you don't like command line tools you can try Win+X Menu Editor (https://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.30)